# Error in loading hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hive and when I started the hive from command prompt in windows...I got the follwing error

```
(A required privilege is not held by the client)
```

Can any one tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo` access and try to restart the program

Comment: I am running hive in windows...Is sudo command available in windows

Comment: @did you try run as Administrator option in Windows

Comment: I got error "Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient" caused by The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MVersionTable" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.

Comment: is there any ubnormal exits, tr removing the lock rm   metastore_db/*.lck

Comment: Yes..it exits abnormally...but there is no .lck in metastore_db

Comment: For those hitting the "MVersionTable/MDatabase is not persistable" issue when trying to run your IDE, I solved this by explicitly adding the metastore jar from standalone-metastore/target to the beginning of my dependencies list for the module I was running.